# Different ways of sliding a div off the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the past few months, I've been showing/hiding things on the edge of the pages like so:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 1000);
```

This works pretty well, it nicely slides the div off the page.

For a complete implementation, refer here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Vmj7/

When you click the link, notice how the text squishes and squished until it leaves the screen? I need an implementation that doesn't do this.

Now, I know the code above uses `"width: 'toggle'"` which really means it's going from 100% width down to 0% width in 1000 ms.

I'm looking for an implementation that doesn't actually shrink the div, but instead just moves the div off the screen without any visual "funkyness".

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you don't animate the position to move the div out of the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** version to work properly cross-browser:

```
$(function() {
    var toHide = $('#myBox').css('overflow', 'hidden').wrapInner('<div></div>'),
        toHideInner = toHide.children(), //the just created <div> element
        width = toHide.outerWidth(),
        i = 0;
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        toHideInner.stop(true).animate({
            marginRight: (i % 2) ? -width : 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/9Vmj7/19/)

Comment: If you plug that into fiddle, it actually extends the width of the screen.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I cannot reproduce the issue you're talking about. And most certainly it could be remedied with a `.hide()` in the callback or by wrapping an element around it with `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera the `true` parameter in `.outerWidth` is to include margins (together with the padding and borders); `.width` does not have that feature. `=]`

Comment: @Fabricio
Here's a fiddle where it expands the width of the window (in Chrome).  
http://jsfiddle.net/schapman/9Vmj7/16/

Looks like you fixed it up though. Nice solution.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I see. I've only tested the first version in Firefox before posting. The bug is fixed on the my answer update.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQueryUI

[Here's a fiddle using jQuery UI and slide](http://jsfiddle.net/schapman/9Vmj7/13/)

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("#myBox").is(":visible")) {
        $('#myBox').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $('#myBox').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    }
```

});​

Answer (score 1):

What about using this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="myBox">
        I am bad and resize when I animate.
    </div>
</div>

<a href="" id="button">click me</a>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#spacer
{
    margin-top:50px;
}

div.parent{
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#myBox{
    float:right;
}
​
```

**JS:**

```
$('#button').toggle(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pxl = $('#myBox').width();
    $('#myBox').stop().animate({
        'margin-right': -pxl+'px'
    }, 1000);
}, function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $('#myBox').stop().animate({
        'margin-right': 0
    }, 1000);    
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/9Vmj7/11/)